# How to run a node auto-scaler script without using a cron-job in Kubernetes ( PKS)

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cron

I have a node auto-scaling shell script which takes care of auto-scaling the worker nodes based on the average CPU/memory of all the nodes in the `Kubernetes` cluster.

I currently run this script from a bastion where I have the `pks`, `kubectl` cli installed and have also configured a cron-job to run it every 5 minutes.

Is there any other way to do this in `Kubernetes` ( `PKS` on AWS) ?

Or may be without using a cron-job, as the auto-scaling becomes completely dependent on the `cron`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR: Autoscale with `k8s`

To setup autoscaling on `k8s` use:

```
kubectl autoscale -f <controller>.yaml --min=3 --max=5
```

### Note: PKS over AWS is an overkill

You mentioned [`PKS`](https://cloud.vmware.com/vmware-enterprise-pks)

Using `PKS` over `AWS` infrastructure seems as overkill. Just because `AWS` has [`EKS`](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/)

To work with `AWS` cloud, VMware [recommends](https://www.vmware.com/ru/products/cloud-foundation.html) [VMC on AWS](https://cloud.vmware.com/vmc-aws)

### `PKS` autoscale

If you do insist to use `PKS` over `AWS`, you may try this sample repo: [pks-autoscale](https://github.com/warroyo/pks-autoscale)

[Author](https://github.com/warroyo/) of the repo also has great [`PKS` quickstart guide for `aws`](https://github.com/warroyo/pks-aws-quickstart)

## Scaling on `AWS`

### `EKS` autoscaling

`AWS` `EKS` [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html) [three-dimensional scaling](https://microservices.io/articles/scalecube.htmlg):

> - [Cluster Autoscaler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html) — The Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler automatically adjusts the number of nodes in your cluster when pods fail to launch due to lack of resources or when nodes in the cluster are underutilized and their pods can be rescheduled on to other nodes in the cluster.
> - [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.html) — The Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of pods in a deployment, replication controller, or replica set based on that resource's CPU utilization.
> - [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/vertical-pod-autoscaler.html) — The Kubernetes Vertical Pod Autoscaler automatically adjusts the CPU and memory reservations for your pods to help "right size" your applications. This can help you to better use your cluster resources and free up CPU and memory for other pods.

### `EC2` Auto Scaling

If you decided to build your own `k8s` cluster using `PKS`, you may use `EC2` auto scaling - just [create an Auto Scaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html#gs-create-asg).

Using `aws-cli`:

```
aws autoscaling create-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name <my-asg> --launch-configuration-name <my-launch-config> --min-size 3 --max-size 5 --vpc-zone-identifier "<zones>
```

### `EC2` predictive scaling

Recently, AWS introduced [predictive scaling for EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-predictive-scaling-for-ec2-powered-by-machine-learning/):

> ... predictive scaling. Using data collected from your actual EC2 usage and further informed by billions of data points drawn from our own observations, we use well-trained Machine Learning models to predict your expected traffic (and EC2 usage) including daily and weekly patterns.

Comment: I agree PKS over AWS has its own pros and cons.

Comment: I was actually looking at - https://github.com/papivot/pks-autoscaler - which is quite simple and easy to use - however as i mentioned here the auto-scaling becomes completely dependent on the cron , I wanted to know if there is any other to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean EKS on AWS than there are different [auto-scaling options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html)